# excel vba list files in a directory where file created date matches week number?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to list all the files in a directory:

```
Sub Example1()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("G:\STOCK\(3) Promotions\Allocations\" & Range("N7").Value & "\" & Range("B7").Value & "\WK " & Range("H7").Value & "\")
i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
'print file PG
    Cells(i + 12, 1) = Range("N7").Value
    'print file Month
    Cells(i + 12, 5) = Range("H7").Value

    'print file Year
    Cells(i + 12, 9) = Range("B7").Value

    'print file name
    Cells(i + 12, 13) = objFile.Name

    'print file path
    Cells(i + 12, 18) = "=hyperlink(""" & objFile.Path & """)"

    i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

This works well. Is there a way I can amend this script to only list the files in this directory where the file created date matches the week number in a cell?

For instance if my cell A1 has a value of 50 - representing week 50, then i want all my files with a date created matching that week number to be listed.

So if my folder directory had the following files:

```
1.pdf (Created 15/12/2016)
2.pdf (Created 01/12/2016)
```

Then the only files which will show in my list would be file 1.pdf because this date falls under week 50.

Please can someone show me how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If Application.WeekNum(objFile.DateCreated) = Range("A1").Value Then
        Debug.Print objFile.Name
        ' ... do the job
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works. I have tried merging this into my code but it doesnt seem to work. Please could you show me how this code would work in context with my existing code?

Comment: @Bing.Wong you simply put the whole body of your loop in the place of my comment `... do the job`. Did you try that?

Comment: i have done this and it doesn't produce an error, it just doesn't do anything? No files are listed :/